# capture keyevent in CellEndEdit of data grid view in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

my datagridview name is DGVall i given code in DGVall_CellEndEdit event

If e.ColumnIndex = 2 Then

```
        If DGVall.CurrentRow.Cells(2).Value = "" Then
            MessageBox.Show("Please Enter Driver ID")
            Exit Sub
        End If
```

befor this i want to check wethar i pressed Enter only ..if i pressed 
enter only i want to execute this.but i am not able to check here wethar i am pressed which control.i am working on vb.net windows application

Comment: You should put this code in CellValueChanged or equivalent (that is, once the value of the cell has changed). Regarding listening the enter key being pressed while editing the cell you should take care of this in other method (and assign a global variable like "enterWasPressed" which will be taken into account by your code above). There is no in-built event to determine whether Enter was pressed when editing a cell of dataGridView, but you can implement your own one pretty easily; helpful link (is in C#):

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/f01a5420-a67d-4eb9-865c-e24cd17ae0f3/handle-up-down-keys-while-editing-a-cell-in-datagridview-to-affect-listbox

Answer (score 1):

You can use an approach like this

```
Private isEnterPress as boolean = false

private sub dgv_EditingControlShowing(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs) Handles dgv.EditingControlShowing
    If dgv.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex = 2 'if column index = 2 then add handler to control
        AddHandler Ctype(e.Control, Textbox).KeyPress, AddresOf TextBox_KeyPress
    End If
End Sub

private sub TextBox_keyPress(byval sender as object, byval e as KeyPressEventArgs)
    If 'check if key press is enter key
        isEnterPress = true
    end if
End Sub
```

Then in `CellEndEdit` event, you can check `isEnterPress` and perform action base on its value. But remember set `isEnterPress` to false when you finish. Hoep this help

NOte: I'm sorry that I forgot how to check if key enter is press and I'm not at my working computer now.

Comment: sir i am not using any text box.i have only grid view.then why you are written TextBox_keyPress event code

Comment: i given code like this: AddHandler CType(sender, TextBox).KeyPress, AddressOf DGVall_KeyPress getting error:Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView' to type 'System.Windows.Forms.TextBox'.

Comment: because of grid view am not able to give like this:?

Comment: You just have change `CType(sender, TextBox)` to `Ctype(e.Control, TextBox)`. `e.Control` will give you access to 'datagridview cell's hosted control', in this case it's a textbox, and you can add your keypress event here.